# Hotmail rejecting SPF records and Python EmailMultiAlternatives

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, dns, spf

I am using EmailMultiAlternatives in a Django(Python)/Ubuntu environment with the following configuration in my TXT records:

-> Name: @

-> Value: v=spf1 ip4:IP_ADDRESS include:_spf.google.com ~all

-> TTL: Default

No hotmail account can receive emails sent from my server with IP_ADDRESS.

I have Google Apps setup through MX, which is working fine.

Further i have been using verification websites which all report the SPF record being valid, i.e. http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html